# Is there any risk to having row IDs visible to users?

Tags: design, database-design, user-interface

In this article, blrfl makes a good case ([How to design a good receipt number](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199446/how-to-design-a-good-receipt-number)) for keeping things simple. Don't encode information into numbers - any information needed can be looked up. I am very much in favour of this, but thinking about it now, I have a slightly tangental question.

If my data has whatever records it has, and the are all simply sequentially numbered (unsigned int), is there any downside to exposing that information to the UI?

In another words, if a user was looking at report #123, and #123 is in fact the unique record id from the table. Is that a problem? The alternative is that I have a second field, with a numerical ID, for UX purposes. So Report #123 is in fact not the actual record ID.

Intuitively, it feels better to obfuscate the inner workings, but does it really matter? Any thoughts / advice?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

> The advantage of natural keys is that they exist already, you don't need to introduce a new "unnatural" value to your data schema. However, the disadvantage of natural keys is that because they have business meaning they are effectively coupled to your business: you may need to rework your key when your business requirements change. For example, if your users decide to make CustomerNumber alphanumeric instead of numeric then in addition to updating the schema for the Customer table (which is unavoidable) you would have to change every single table where CustomerNumber is used as a foreign key.

I personally have found that using surrogate keys is generally cheap and easy enough and pays when the schema needs to evolve.

Comment: Maybe just add that if you show your users the ids they WILL become business ids that they then want to change :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple of issues.

1. The user knows the Ids of records < the exposed Id
2. The user can guess subsequent record Ids
3. The user knows you have >= the exposed Id records.

Now, how bad these things are depends on the rest of your setup, but they can be subtle.

Say for example I am an investor, I place an order each month and note the id number. I now have a rough measure of your monthly sales and, seeing numbers less that predicted I sell my shares before your annual report, then immediately buy them back after they fall.

Your security might prevent any obvious malicious use, such as accessing other peoples records, but still you have effectively lost money

Answer (score 1):

I'll do my best to make another good case here.  :-)

There's no concrete answer; it's all a matter of evaluating the risks.  You have to look at your system and figure out:

- What harm, if any, will come from a user being able to easily guess the IDs of your records
- What controls you have in place to prevent access where you don't want it
- What harm would come from miscommunication or miskeying of information (e.g., entering `156` instead of `159` when both are valid)
- What other information can be gleaned from watching the sequence number increment.

If you're IMDB, the IDs don't really matter, and theirs are, in fact, sequential.  Someone looking at the [entry for *Young Frankenstein*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072431) can change the last digit in the title ID and pull up the entry for [*Zandy's Bride*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072435/) instead.  There's no harm in viewing those records because pretty much everything on the site is content they want you to see, and seeing another page means one more opportunity to put promotional material in front of your eyeballs.  End users can alter the records, but doing that depends on getting past an access control.  Entering the wrong one means you see the wrong movie, which becomes obvious because the title is the first thing on the retrieved page.  They also probably don't care that you can look at the sequence number for titles today and a week from now and figure out the number of movies that were released during that week.

If you're an e-commerce site, it does matter.  Letting a third party who placed order `2620453` see the status for order `2620452` risks financial loss for me or my customer if it becomes apparent that a valuable item will be delivered to my house at 1010 Disk Drive on Tuesday and that information is used to steal it while I'm still at work.  That sort of thing was a problem in the early days of online shopping.  Sites not developed by naifs that use sequential order numbers now require something you know about the order like the ship-to ZIP code as a second factor for access control if they don't already require a full sign-in.  Canceling a mis-keyed order number without verifying that it's the correct customer and order could risk losing future business.  And the last thing you want is competitors brute-forcing your order numbers to figure out whether or not they're doing more or less business than you are, which is a good reason for a hard-to-guess, external-facing key.

Your mention of UX hints that the IDs are probably not going to be handled just by machines, so there's also a need to consider usability.  Type 4 UUIDs make great second keys because they're hard to guess and rarely collide.  Put a human in the loop trying to get 32 hex digits to a dispatcher across a flaky radio link and they become really awful really quickly.  Sequential IDs might just as bad for the same reason because one end might say he's at site *three-oh-six*, the other end could hear *three-eight-six* and a truck gets sent to a valid-but-wrong place.  Short hashes, perhaps with a check digit, might be a viable alternative depending on how many records you have, how much tolerance your users have for longer IDs and how important it is to avoid wrong entries.